# Is there a faster way to get the vector fields smoothed with Gaussian weight function on lattice?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pixel

Basically, we have N=10000 particles in a *two-dimensional* system, and for clarity, only N=1000 particles are shown in the left panel. For each particle, there's a so-called *polar vector* corrosponding to it. The positions and corrosponding polar vectors of particles are known, and what I need to do it to pixelate the vector fields using *2D Gaussian weight function*. In formula, the procedure is as below:
[image: Formula]

[image: Polar vector fields in simulation data and smoothed with Gaussian weight function]

**Left**: Polar vector fields in simulation data, subject to uncertainty. **Right**: Polar vector fields smoothed with Gaussian weight function, with standard deviation [image: Formula], truncated at [image: Formula].

My pseudocode works like this, and it is low-efficient for the huge for loops:

```
weighted_vector_sum_on_lattice = np.zeros((nPixelsInOneDim, nPixelsInOneDim, 2))
sum_weight = np.zeros((nPixelsInOneDim, nPixelsInOneDim))
sum_x = np.zeros((nPixelsInOneDim, nPixelsInOneDim))
sum_y = np.zeros((nPixelsInOneDim, nPixelsInOneDim))
# scan for all atoms
for x_pixel_index in range(nPixelsInOneDim):
    for y_pixel_index in range(nPixelsInOneDim):
        # calculate the coordinate of the pixel
        coordinate_of_pixel = get_coordinates_from_pixel_indices([x_pixel_index, y_pixel_index])
        # calculate a scalar cell index
        serial_cell_index_ij = get_cell_index_of_point(coordinate_of_pixel)
        # get vector cell index
        i_th_cell, j_th_cell = get_vector_cell_index(serial_cell_index_ij)
        # scan the neighbor cells (including itself) of cell c
        for a in [-1, 0, 1]:
            for b in [-1, 0, 1]:
                k_th_cell = i_th_cell + a
                l_th_cell = j_th_cell + b
                # periodic boundary condition by shifting coordinates
                k_th_cell %= nCellsInOneDim
                l_th_cell %= nCellsInOneDim
                # calculate the scalar cell index of the neighbor cell
                serial_cell_index_kl = get_serial_cell_index(k_th_cell, l_th_cell)
                # get atoms in the neighbor cells
                atoms_in_kl_subcell = get_atoms_in_subcell(serial_cell_index_kl, head_of_chain, linked_list)
                # scan atoms in neighbor cells
                for atom_index_j in atoms_in_kl_subcell:
                    dist = get_distance(coordinate_of_pixel, coordinates[atom_index_j])
                    if dist <= filter_radius:
                        weight = get_gaussian(dist, standard_deviation)
                        sum_weight[x_pixel_index, y_pixel_index] += weight
                        sum_x[x_pixel_index, y_pixel_index] += weight * eigenvector[atom_index_j][0]
                        sum_y[x_pixel_index, y_pixel_index] += weight * eigenvector[atom_index_j][1]
weighted_vector_sum_on_lattice[:, :, 0] = sum_x/sum_weight
weighted_vector_sum_on_lattice[:, :, 1] = sum_y/sum_weight
```

I wonder if there is a faster way to get the vector fields smoothed with Gaussian weight function on lattice?

Comment: Does `N=1000...` really need to be an image?

Comment: @Mad Physicist Sorry, it's a somewhat personal habbit when I write things related with Maths. Thanks a lot for your comment!

Comment: Given that your code works, you might consider posting it on [codereview.se]

Comment: Regarding your code, the best is probably to try to use Cython or Numba due to the function calls and the conditions. Note that Numba provide some fancy stencil decorator that may help you to optimize your code further.